# Python: How to select columns that contain specific months of a year?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+------------+-----------+-----+-----+----------+----------+-----+------------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
| State_Name | City_Name | ID1 | ID2 | 1/1/2020 | 1/2/2020 | ... | 12/31/2020 | 1/1/2021 | 1/2/2021 | ... | 12/31/2021 |
+------------+-----------+-----+-----+----------+----------+-----+------------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
| ...        | ...       | ... | ... | ...      | ...      | ... | ...        | ...      | ...      | ... | ...        |
+------------+-----------+-----+-----+----------+----------+-----+------------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
| ...        | ...       | ... | ... | ...      | ...      | ... | ...        | ...      | ...      | ... | ...        |
+------------+-----------+-----+-----+----------+----------+-----+------------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
```

I have a lot of columns from 1/1/2020 all the way to 12/31/2021. How do I select columns that contain specific months of a year? For example, if I want select columns that contain July 2021 data, I can subset columns with name '7/1/2021', '7/2/2021'......'7/31/2021'?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Are the `1/1/2020 ` strings?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter` method:

```
df.filter(regex='7/\d{1,2}/2021', axis=1)
```

Comment: `df.filter(regex='^7')` but only works with strings. Not my downvote btw.

Comment: How about : `df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)` and then using `filter` ?

Comment: I'm just changing them to `str` type. Am I not?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest store all non datetime columns to `MultiIndex`, convert all another columns to `datetimes`:

```
print (df)
  State_Name City_Name ID1 ID2  7/1/2021  1/7/2020  7/05/2021  1/1/2021  \
0          a         b   s   d         7         8          5         6   

   1/2/2021  12/31/2021  
0         3           8  

df = df.set_index(['State_Name','City_Name','ID1','ID2'])
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
```

And for select july 2021 use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns.strftime('%m-%Y') == '07-2021']
```

Or compare by month periods by [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns.to_period('m') == '2021-07']
print (df1)
                              2021-07-01  2021-07-05
State_Name City_Name ID1 ID2                        
a          b         s   d             7           5
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, (df.columns.year == 2021) & (df.columns.month == 7)]
print (df1)
                              2021-07-01  2021-07-05
State_Name City_Name ID1 ID2                        
a          b         s   d             7           5
```

Answer (score 1):

One nice solution could be to use `melt` to transform the various date columns into values in a single date columns.

For example:

```
# make dataframe from sample data
data = {
    "State_Name": ['state1', 'state2'],
    "City_Name": ['city1', 'city2'],
    "ID1": ['ID1_A', 'ID1_B'],
    "ID2": ['ID2_A', 'ID2_B'],
    "1/1/2020": ['dog', 'cat'],
    "1/2/2020": ['house', 'mouse']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# melt date columns into a row
melted_df = df.melt(
    id_vars=["State_Name", "City_Name", "ID1", "ID2"],
    var_name="date")
```

`df` looks like this:

|  | State_Name | City_Name | ID1 | ID2 | 1/1/2020 | 1/2/2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | state1 | city1 | ID1_A | ID2_A | dog | house |
| 1 | state2 | city2 | ID1_B | ID2_B | cat | mouse |

And `melted_df` looks like this:

|  | State_Name | City_Name | ID1 | ID2 | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | state1 | city1 | ID1_A | ID2_A | 1/1/2020 | dog |
| 1 | state2 | city2 | ID1_B | ID2_B | 1/1/2020 | cat |
| 2 | state1 | city1 | ID1_A | ID2_A | 1/2/2020 | house |
| 3 | state2 | city2 | ID1_B | ID2_B | 1/2/2020 | mouse |

This makes it a bit more natural to select data based on dates. For instance, you could mark the date column as type `datetime` and select rows based on a date range.

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('1/1/2020')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('1/1/2020')

# select rows where date is between given start/end date (inclusive)
sel_df = melted_df.loc[
    (melted_df['date'] >= start_date) & (melted_df['date'] <= end_date)
]
```

If you want to undo the melt, and the dates into columns again, you can use `pivot`. Eg.,

```
sel_df.pivot(columns='date', values='value')
```